# Scalar arrays error in range function - Python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to place a certain values in a 1D array (based on an index), but when I insert the index to the range function in the for loop - I get the error:

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

x = np.arange(0, 24, 0.05)   # (Start #, Last #, Jump)
x.size
n, = np.where(x == 6)
y = x

for i in range(0,n):
    y[i] = 0
```

I don't understand why this is happening because n suppose to be an index itself no?

Thank you!

Comment: I can run your code without any error! what's version of your Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) returns a ndarray. You need to use only the first element

```
for i in range(n[0]):
    y[i] = 0
```